# How to manage multiple Airplay receivers on iOS?

Tags: ios, airplay

I want to create an app that can play music from my iOS device to multiple Airplay speakers. I know that `MPVolumeView` natively lets you do this on 1 Airplay receiver, so that is not the solution I need. There is an iOS app in the store that does this: [Whaale](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multiroom-music-radio-player/id663776918?mt=8).

[image]

How do they do it? I am happy to use private APIs, as I do not plan to release this as a public app right now.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot answer specifically, I can point you to a few things I've discovered:
 - There are a few apps that do this for IOS.
 - All of them have the limitation that they can only stream music that is not through itunes and that exist on the device as music files.
 - no streaming is available (Pandora, Spotify, etc.)

Good Luck!
Robert